# Can't insert data to database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Iam using the newest version of CI (3.1.6)
The problem is the data I want to insert can't post to the controller, so if I print out the data from view, it can't catch any data from the form. I think the problem's located in the form. but I don'r know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?
Here's my code

My form.php code

```
<div id="register" class="text-center">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title center">
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <hr>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
      <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
   <!--    <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Retype Password"> -->
      <ul>
      <p1>Gender</p1>
      <select name="gender" id="" class="pilihan">
        <option value="men">Male</option>
        <option value="women">Female</option></select>
      </ul>
      <ul>
      <p1>Occupation</p1>
      <li><input type="radio" name="job" value="doctor" checked> Doctor<br></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="job" value="nurse"> Nurse<br></li>
    </ul>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/user/login.css">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url('c_register/do_insert'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">Primary link</a>
  </form>
```

my controller code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_register extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_register');
    }


    function do_insert(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'fullname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'pass', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('job', 'job', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            echo "gagal diinsert";
            // $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            // $this->load->view('news/comment_form');
            // $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->m_register->InsertData();
            $this->load->view('dashboard');
        }
    }
}?>
```

my mode code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_register extends CI_Model {

    public function InsertData($tabelName, $data){
         $datac = array(
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'pass' => $this->input->post('pass'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'job' => $this->input->post('job')
        );

        $res =  $this->db->insert('member', $datac);
        return $res;

    }

    }
?
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn,t load the database class on your controller constructor like this.

```
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_register'); 
    $this->load->database();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem to address is the model's method `InsertData()`. You have defined it in the model to require two parameters - `$tableName` and `$data`

```
public function InsertData($tabelName, $data){
```

But in the controller you call the method without providing any parameters.

```
    } else {
        $this->m_register->InsertData(); //No parameters???
```

So, you either need to pass the parameters or change the definition of the method.  Here is a much simpler version that will get the insert job done and you don't need to change the controller.

```
public function InsertData()
{
    $datac = $this->input->post();
    return $this->db->insert('member', $datac);
}
```

You don't need to get each input one at a time. Calling `input->post()` without passing a field name will return an array with all the fields. That means you don't have to manually create the `$datac` array.

Also, it's less typing to simply return what `$this->db->insert` returns instead of saving it to a var and then returning the var.

Now, why doesn't the newly inserted data display? Probably because after you call `$this->m_register->InsertData();` you call `$this->load->view('dashboard');` but are not providing any data for the 'dashboard' view to display.

I think what you really want to do is `redirect` to the controller/method that shows the dashboard. Assuming the controller is `Dashboard` and the method is `index()` the last part of `do_insert()` should probably look something like this.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    echo "gagal diinsert";
    // $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    // $this->load->view('news/comment_form');
    // $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
else
{
    if($this->m_register->InsertData())
    {
        redirect('dashboard'); 
    }
    else
    {
        //show an error page or error message about the failed insert
    }
}
```

Comment: i change my code like you say and still can't insert the code to my db @DFriend

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add the model. You can use the easy way like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_register extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_register');
    }


    function do_insert(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'fullname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'pass', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('job', 'job', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            echo "gagal diinsert";
        } else {
            //check in the array that it is same as column name in table like 'firstname' will be present on the table        
            $datac = array(
                'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'pass' => $this->input->post('pass'),
                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'job' => $this->input->post('job')
            );

            $this->db->insert('member', $datac);
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            if(!empty($insert_id)){
                $this->load->view('dashboard');
            }else{
                echo "failed";           
            }

        }
    }
}?>
```